# images not showing up in taxonomy view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, media, ubercart

When I look at one of my catalog pages (www.foo.com/catalog/category) - i get a grid listing of all the products with images (Content: Image product image linked to node).

However,  when I view any other taxonomy listing (www.foo.com/brand/xyz), I do get a grid listing of all products from brand xyz, but no image. I set up a view that has the same fields as uc_products and tied it to this taxonomy/term/%.

All of my fields show up (title, price, add to cart button), but there is no image link being generated.

Do you have any idea why the image is not showing up in the taxonomy listing, but it is for catalog/?

I'm using Ubercart 2.x, and Drupal 6.

---

If I add/remove other fields from the view, I see them; it is just the images that don't appear.

Comment: I found the problem and thought I'd share.  It turns out it was a permissions issue.  Once i went in and allowed image_field_cache for anonymous and authorized, it works.  Just stumbled across the solution by accident, but in case anyone has the same issue, that fixed it for me.